# get certain amount of files with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I want to read for example 5 files out of a directory. i know how to count all the files and display them but what i want is:

start with the first 5 images. when you click on an arrow, show the next 5, click on the arrow, show the  next 5

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator(__DIR__) as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile()) {
        print '- ' . $file->getFilename() . "<br>";
    }
}
$fi = new FilesystemIterator(__DIR__, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
printf("There were %d Files", iterator_count($fi));
```

it basically has to be something like the windows 10 background chooser
[W10 Background chooser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbtWG.png)
only instead of the 'browse' button, with 'next 5' and 'previous 5' arrows.

Comment: Do a google search for ajax calls and pagination or endless scrolling on the client side.

Comment: You need an efficient way to find the current selection and to traverse the files. This is usually done with the help of a database.

Comment: I think the best solution for you will depend on why you need pagination. Are you addressing a performance consideration (backend) or a UX consideration (front-end)

Comment: @AndFisher i wanted to have it as a UX consideration, since its just a small row of images there is no performance issue, i've kept it at a simple side scroller for now and will try to improve on it later on

Comment: Then I'd load all of the data into a JSON once and hide/show a subset of that data via JavaScript, then you don't need to AJAX the backend saving requests.